# JQUERY animate не работает несколько раз подряд

Tags: javascript, jquery

И так, вот код ниже, он крутит тюленюшку по кнопке, делает 2 оборота + случайные 100-300 градусов. Так вот если нажать кнопку, подождать завершения кручения, и нажать ее ещё раз, то он начнет анимацию с того места где он закончил (rotate). Мне нужно чтобы он каждый раз заново от 0 deg крутил тюленюшку. Я задавал до анимации css transform rotate 0deg, не помогало.

```js
jQuery.easing['jswing'] = jQuery.easing['swing'];

jQuery.extend( jQuery.easing,
{
 def: 'easeOutQuad',
 swing: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
  //alert(jQuery.easing.default);
  return jQuery.easing[jQuery.easing.def](x, t, b, c, d);
 },
 easeInQuad: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
  return c*(t/=d)*t + b;
 },
 easeOutQuad: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
  return -c *(t/=d)*(t-2) + b;
 },
 easeInOutQuad: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
  if ((t/=d/2) < 1) return c/2*t*t + b;
  return -c/2 * ((--t)*(t-2) - 1) + b;
 },
 easeInCubic: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
  return c*(t/=d)*t*t + b;
 },
 easeOutCubic: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
  return c*((t=t/d-1)*t*t + 1) + b;
 },
 easeInOutCubic: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
  if ((t/=d/2) < 1) return c/2*t*t*t + b;
  return c/2*((t-=2)*t*t + 2) + b;
 },
 easeInQuart: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
  return c*(t/=d)*t*t*t + b;
 },
 easeOutQuart: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
  return -c * ((t=t/d-1)*t*t*t - 1) + b;
 },
 easeInOutQuart: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
  if ((t/=d/2) < 1) return c/2*t*t*t*t + b;
  return -c/2 * ((t-=2)*t*t*t - 2) + b;
 },
 easeInQuint: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
  return c*(t/=d)*t*t*t*t + b;
 },
 easeOutQuint: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
  return c*((t=t/d-1)*t*t*t*t + 1) + b;
 },
 easeInOutQuint: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
  if ((t/=d/2) < 1) return c/2*t*t*t*t*t + b;
  return c/2*((t-=2)*t*t*t*t + 2) + b;
 },
 easeInSine: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
  return -c * Math.cos(t/d * (Math.PI/2)) + c + b;
 },
 easeOutSine: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
  return c * Math.sin(t/d * (Math.PI/2)) + b;
 },
 easeInOutSine: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
  return -c/2 * (Math.cos(Math.PI*t/d) - 1) + b;
 },
 easeInExpo: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
  return (t==0) ? b : c * Math.pow(2, 10 * (t/d - 1)) + b;
 },
 easeOutExpo: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
  return (t==d) ? b+c : c * (-Math.pow(2, -10 * t/d) + 1) + b;
 },
 easeInOutExpo: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
  if (t==0) return b;
  if (t==d) return b+c;
  if ((t/=d/2) < 1) return c/2 * Math.pow(2, 10 * (t - 1)) + b;
  return c/2 * (-Math.pow(2, -10 * --t) + 2) + b;
 },
 easeInCirc: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
  return -c * (Math.sqrt(1 - (t/=d)*t) - 1) + b;
 },
 easeOutCirc: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
  return c * Math.sqrt(1 - (t=t/d-1)*t) + b;
 },
 easeInOutCirc: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
  if ((t/=d/2) < 1) return -c/2 * (Math.sqrt(1 - t*t) - 1) + b;
  return c/2 * (Math.sqrt(1 - (t-=2)*t) + 1) + b;
 },
 easeInElastic: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
  var s=1.70158;var p=0;var a=c;
  if (t==0) return b;  if ((t/=d)==1) return b+c;  if (!p) p=d*.3;
  if (a < Math.abs(c)) { a=c; var s=p/4; }
  else var s = p/(2*Math.PI) * Math.asin (c/a);
  return -(a*Math.pow(2,10*(t-=1)) * Math.sin( (t*d-s)*(2*Math.PI)/p )) + b;
 },
 easeOutElastic: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
  var s=1.70158;var p=0;var a=c;
  if (t==0) return b;  if ((t/=d)==1) return b+c;  if (!p) p=d*.3;
  if (a < Math.abs(c)) { a=c; var s=p/4; }
  else var s = p/(2*Math.PI) * Math.asin (c/a);
  return a*Math.pow(2,-10*t) * Math.sin( (t*d-s)*(2*Math.PI)/p ) + c + b;
 },
 easeInOutElastic: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
  var s=1.70158;var p=0;var a=c;
  if (t==0) return b;  if ((t/=d/2)==2) return b+c;  if (!p) p=d*(.3*1.5);
  if (a < Math.abs(c)) { a=c; var s=p/4; }
  else var s = p/(2*Math.PI) * Math.asin (c/a);
  if (t < 1) return -.5*(a*Math.pow(2,10*(t-=1)) * Math.sin( (t*d-s)*(2*Math.PI)/p )) + b;
  return a*Math.pow(2,-10*(t-=1)) * Math.sin( (t*d-s)*(2*Math.PI)/p )*.5 + c + b;
 },
 easeInBack: function (x, t, b, c, d, s) {
  if (s == undefined) s = 1.70158;
  return c*(t/=d)*t*((s+1)*t - s) + b;
 },
 easeOutBack: function (x, t, b, c, d, s) {
  if (s == undefined) s = 1.70158;
  return c*((t=t/d-1)*t*((s+1)*t + s) + 1) + b;
 },
 easeInOutBack: function (x, t, b, c, d, s) {
  if (s == undefined) s = 1.70158; 
  if ((t/=d/2) < 1) return c/2*(t*t*(((s*=(1.525))+1)*t - s)) + b;
  return c/2*((t-=2)*t*(((s*=(1.525))+1)*t + s) + 2) + b;
 },
 easeInBounce: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
  return c - jQuery.easing.easeOutBounce (x, d-t, 0, c, d) + b;
 },
 easeOutBounce: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
  if ((t/=d) < (1/2.75)) {
   return c*(7.5625*t*t) + b;
  } else if (t < (2/2.75)) {
   return c*(7.5625*(t-=(1.5/2.75))*t + .75) + b;
  } else if (t < (2.5/2.75)) {
   return c*(7.5625*(t-=(2.25/2.75))*t + .9375) + b;
  } else {
   return c*(7.5625*(t-=(2.625/2.75))*t + .984375) + b;
  }
 },
 easeInOutBounce: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
  if (t < d/2) return jQuery.easing.easeInBounce (x, t*2, 0, c, d) * .5 + b;
  return jQuery.easing.easeOutBounce (x, t*2-d, 0, c, d) * .5 + c*.5 + b;
 }
});


function getRandomArbitary(min, max)
{
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}

function test(){

$("#content-wheel-canvas").animate({rotation: 720 + getRandomArbitary(100,300)},
    {
       duration: 8000,
    easing: "easeOutCubic",
       step: function(now, fx) {
           
            $(this).css({"transform": "rotate("+now+"deg)"});
       }
    }); 
    }
   
   
$( "#test" ).click(function() {
 test();
});
```

```css
#content-wheel {
    padding-top: 60px;
    padding-bottom: 70px;
    position: relative
}
#content-wheel-pointer {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    bottom: 85px
}
#content-wrapper {
    background-color: #26262c;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    padding-bottom: 30px
}
#wheel-pointer {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    height: 24px;
    width: 24px;
    padding-top: 16px;
    -webkit-transition: .1s ease;
    -moz-transition: .1s ease;
    -ms-transition: .1s ease;
    -o-transition: .1s ease;
    transition: .1s ease;
    color: transparent;
    opacity: 0
}
.duel-wheel-pointer {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    text-align: center;
    top: 145px;
    color: #333
}
#content-wheel-canvas {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%
}
#content-wheel-canvas-wrapper {
    margin: auto;
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    transform: rotate(180deg)
}
#wheel {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    background: url(https://image.ibb.co/d7xykG/image_big_0014489.png) no-repeat center;
    background-size: 100%
}
#content-wheel-balance {
    position: absolute;
    left: 40px;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 60px;
    z-index: 1
}
#content-wheel-autobetter {
    position: absolute;
    left: 40px;
    right: 0;
    top: 250px;
    z-index: 1;
    display: none
}
#content-wheel-timer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 125px;
    width: 100%
}
#wheel-timer {
    display: none;
    margin: auto;
    width: 400px;
    opacity: 1;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #444;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 300
}
#content-wheel {
    padding-top: 60px;
    padding-bottom: 70px;
    position: relative
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button style="width: 200px; height: 30px;" id="test" >ЖМИ</button>
 </button>
 <div id="content-wrapper">
<div id="content-wheel">
               <div id="content-wheel-canvas-wrapper">
                  <div id="content-wheel-canvas" class="noselect" style="transform: rotate(1060.07deg);">
                     <div id="wheel" style="opacity: 1;"></div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
              </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

или вообще убрать эти значения от предыдущей анимации (продолжая идею  которую предложил @Дмитрий Полянин ). добавив код

```
 $("#content-wheel-canvas").css("rotation", "");
```

получается, например, так:

```js
jQuery.easing['jswing'] = jQuery.easing['swing'];

jQuery.extend(jQuery.easing, {
  def: 'easeOutQuad',
  swing: function(x, t, b, c, d) {
    //alert(jQuery.easing.default);
    return jQuery.easing[jQuery.easing.def](x, t, b, c, d);
  },
  easeInQuad: function(x, t, b, c, d) {
    return c * (t /= d) * t + b;
  },
  easeOutQuad: function(x, t, b, c, d) {
    return -c * (t /= d) * (t - 2) + b;
  },
  easeInOutQuad: function(x, t, b, c, d) {
    if ((t /= d / 2) < 1) return c / 2 * t * t + b;
    return -c / 2 * ((--t) * (t - 2) - 1) + b;
  },
  easeInCubic: function(x, t, b, c, d) {
    return c * (t /= d) * t * t + b;
  },
  easeOutCubic: function(x, t, b, c, d) {
    return c * ((t = t / d - 1) * t * t + 1) + b;
  },
  easeInOutCubic: function(x, t, b, c, d) {
    if ((t /= d / 2) < 1) return c / 2 * t * t * t + b;
    return c / 2 * ((t -= 2) * t * t + 2) + b;
  },
  easeInQuart: function(x, t, b, c, d) {
    return c * (t /= d) * t * t * t + b;
  },
  easeOutQuart: function(x, t, b, c, d) {
    return -c * ((t = t / d - 1) * t * t * t - 1) + b;
  },
  easeInOutQuart: function(x, t, b, c, d) {
    if ((t /= d / 2) < 1) return c / 2 * t * t * t * t + b;
    return -c / 2 * ((t -= 2) * t * t * t - 2) + b;
  },
  easeInQuint: function(x, t, b, c, d) {
    return c * (t /= d) * t * t * t * t + b;
  },
  easeOutQuint: function(x, t, b, c, d) {
    return c * ((t = t / d - 1) * t * t * t * t + 1) + b;
  },
  easeInOutQuint: function(x, t, b, c, d) {
    if ((t /= d / 2) < 1) return c / 2 * t * t * t * t * t + b;
    return c / 2 * ((t -= 2) * t * t * t * t + 2) + b;
  },
  easeInSine: function(x, t, b, c, d) {
    return -c * Math.cos(t / d * (Math.PI / 2)) + c + b;
  },
  easeOutSine: function(x, t, b, c, d) {
    return c * Math.sin(t / d * (Math.PI / 2)) + b;
  },
  easeInOutSine: function(x, t, b, c, d) {
    return -c / 2 * (Math.cos(Math.PI * t / d) - 1) + b;
  },
  easeInExpo: function(x, t, b, c, d) {
    return (t == 0) ? b : c * Math.pow(2, 10 * (t / d - 1)) + b;
  },
  easeOutExpo: function(x, t, b, c, d) {
    return (t == d) ? b + c : c * (-Math.pow(2, -10 * t / d) + 1) + b;
  },
  easeInOutExpo: function(x, t, b, c, d) {
    if (t == 0) return b;
    if (t == d) return b + c;
    if ((t /= d / 2) < 1) return c / 2 * Math.pow(2, 10 * (t - 1)) + b;
    return c / 2 * (-Math.pow(2, -10 * --t) + 2) + b;
  },
  easeInCirc: function(x, t, b, c, d) {
    return -c * (Math.sqrt(1 - (t /= d) * t) - 1) + b;
  },
  easeOutCirc: function(x, t, b, c, d) {
    return c * Math.sqrt(1 - (t = t / d - 1) * t) + b;
  },
  easeInOutCirc: function(x, t, b, c, d) {
    if ((t /= d / 2) < 1) return -c / 2 * (Math.sqrt(1 - t * t) - 1) + b;
    return c / 2 * (Math.sqrt(1 - (t -= 2) * t) + 1) + b;
  },
  easeInElastic: function(x, t, b, c, d) {
    var s = 1.70158;
    var p = 0;
    var a = c;
    if (t == 0) return b;
    if ((t /= d) == 1) return b + c;
    if (!p) p = d * .3;
    if (a < Math.abs(c)) {
      a = c;
      var s = p / 4;
    } else var s = p / (2 * Math.PI) * Math.asin(c / a);
    return -(a * Math.pow(2, 10 * (t -= 1)) * Math.sin((t * d - s) * (2 * Math.PI) / p)) + b;
  },
  easeOutElastic: function(x, t, b, c, d) {
    var s = 1.70158;
    var p = 0;
    var a = c;
    if (t == 0) return b;
    if ((t /= d) == 1) return b + c;
    if (!p) p = d * .3;
    if (a < Math.abs(c)) {
      a = c;
      var s = p / 4;
    } else var s = p / (2 * Math.PI) * Math.asin(c / a);
    return a * Math.pow(2, -10 * t) * Math.sin((t * d - s) * (2 * Math.PI) / p) + c + b;
  },
  easeInOutElastic: function(x, t, b, c, d) {
    var s = 1.70158;
    var p = 0;
    var a = c;
    if (t == 0) return b;
    if ((t /= d / 2) == 2) return b + c;
    if (!p) p = d * (.3 * 1.5);
    if (a < Math.abs(c)) {
      a = c;
      var s = p / 4;
    } else var s = p / (2 * Math.PI) * Math.asin(c / a);
    if (t < 1) return -.5 * (a * Math.pow(2, 10 * (t -= 1)) * Math.sin((t * d - s) * (2 * Math.PI) / p)) + b;
    return a * Math.pow(2, -10 * (t -= 1)) * Math.sin((t * d - s) * (2 * Math.PI) / p) * .5 + c + b;
  },
  easeInBack: function(x, t, b, c, d, s) {
    if (s == undefined) s = 1.70158;
    return c * (t /= d) * t * ((s + 1) * t - s) + b;
  },
  easeOutBack: function(x, t, b, c, d, s) {
    if (s == undefined) s = 1.70158;
    return c * ((t = t / d - 1) * t * ((s + 1) * t + s) + 1) + b;
  },
  easeInOutBack: function(x, t, b, c, d, s) {
    if (s == undefined) s = 1.70158;
    if ((t /= d / 2) < 1) return c / 2 * (t * t * (((s *= (1.525)) + 1) * t - s)) + b;
    return c / 2 * ((t -= 2) * t * (((s *= (1.525)) + 1) * t + s) + 2) + b;
  },
  easeInBounce: function(x, t, b, c, d) {
    return c - jQuery.easing.easeOutBounce(x, d - t, 0, c, d) + b;
  },
  easeOutBounce: function(x, t, b, c, d) {
    if ((t /= d) < (1 / 2.75)) {
      return c * (7.5625 * t * t) + b;
    } else if (t < (2 / 2.75)) {
      return c * (7.5625 * (t -= (1.5 / 2.75)) * t + .75) + b;
    } else if (t < (2.5 / 2.75)) {
      return c * (7.5625 * (t -= (2.25 / 2.75)) * t + .9375) + b;
    } else {
      return c * (7.5625 * (t -= (2.625 / 2.75)) * t + .984375) + b;
    }
  },
  easeInOutBounce: function(x, t, b, c, d) {
    if (t < d / 2) return jQuery.easing.easeInBounce(x, t * 2, 0, c, d) * .5 + b;
    return jQuery.easing.easeOutBounce(x, t * 2 - d, 0, c, d) * .5 + c * .5 + b;
  }
});


function getRandomArbitary(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}

function test() {
  $("#content-wheel-canvas").css("rotation", "");
  $("#content-wheel-canvas").animate({
    rotation: 720 + getRandomArbitary(100, 300)
  }, {
    duration: 8000,
    easing: "easeOutCubic",
    step: function(now, fx) {

      $(this).css({
        "transform": "rotate(" + now + "deg)"
      });
    }
  });
}


$("#test").click(function() {
  test();
});
```

```css
#content-wheel {
  padding-top: 60px;
  padding-bottom: 70px;
  position: relative
}

#content-wheel-pointer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  bottom: 85px
}

#content-wrapper {
  background-color: #26262c;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  padding-bottom: 30px
}

#wheel-pointer {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
  padding-top: 16px;
  -webkit-transition: .1s ease;
  -moz-transition: .1s ease;
  -ms-transition: .1s ease;
  -o-transition: .1s ease;
  transition: .1s ease;
  color: transparent;
  opacity: 0
}

.duel-wheel-pointer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  text-align: center;
  top: 145px;
  color: #333
}

#content-wheel-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%
}

#content-wheel-canvas-wrapper {
  margin: auto;
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  transform: rotate(180deg)
}

#wheel {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  background: url(https://image.ibb.co/d7xykG/image_big_0014489.png) no-repeat center;
  background-size: 100%
}

#content-wheel-balance {
  position: absolute;
  left: 40px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 60px;
  z-index: 1
}

#content-wheel-autobetter {
  position: absolute;
  left: 40px;
  right: 0;
  top: 250px;
  z-index: 1;
  display: none
}

#content-wheel-timer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 125px;
  width: 100%
}

#wheel-timer {
  display: none;
  margin: auto;
  width: 400px;
  opacity: 1;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #444;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 300
}

#content-wheel {
  padding-top: 60px;
  padding-bottom: 70px;
  position: relative
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button style="width: 200px; height: 30px;" id="test">ЖМИ</button>
</button>
<div id="content-wrapper">
  <div id="content-wheel">
    <div id="content-wheel-canvas-wrapper">
      <div id="content-wheel-canvas" class="noselect" style="transform: rotate(1060.07deg);">
        <div id="wheel" style="opacity: 1;"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Он продолжает с того же места где закончил, ведь jquery.animate меняет сами значения параметров при анимации, то есть после анимации новые значения уже записаны в объект. Если вы хотите крутить с начала вам просто необходимо перед новой анимацией вручную установить начальные значения.

То есть в самом начале вызова `test()` вы делаете `SetStartValues()`. Разумеется `SetStartValues()` вам самим придётся реализовать.

Comment: eсли написать перед анимэйт $("#content-wheel-canvas").css({"transform": "rotate(0deg)"}); то не работает. или я не понимаю какие параметры

Comment: @LorDo видимо это относительный поворот а не абсолютный... то есть ты поворачиваешь ещё на 0 градусов, что не работает никак. Тебе надо в явную задать значение. Попробуй просто задать transform: unset; для скидывания значения.